# Transatlantic road paint

Tags: word, english, open-ended

In the US, text painted on roads reads bottom to top:

```
AHEAD
STOP
```

In the UK, it reads like normal text:

```
 NO
ENTRY
```

Obligatory XKCD:

[image]

The task here is to come up with the longest text (measured in number of words) that can be read as an *instruction to drivers* in both US and UK use. This doesn't need to be a road safety/direction message per se, but relevant to driving or driving journeys.

So "STOP AHEAD" could be read as "AHEAD(,) STOP" scoring 2, while "ENTRY NO" isn't valid as the only sensible expansion is "ENTRY? NO" and not an instruction.

After having a loophole pointed out to me : the number of characters in a line should not exceed 8 unless they form a single (non-hyphenated) word. The exact number is based on examples seem in the wild (by me)

Comment: As this is my first question submission here, *please* give feedback if you don't like it, think it shoudl be improved/clarified etc.

Comment: +1 I find this is a great question ! But do the text has to be about road safety or could it be any text we want?

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer "an instruction to drivers" was maybe a bit vague -- but as we have examples of instructions like "take a break" (paired with "Tiredness kills" it can be pretty open. I'll try to tweak the wording now.

Comment: What do you think about `Don't mix Drink and Drive`?

Comment: @ChrisH In my experience, challenges of the form "come up with the longest sentence so that X" tend to devolve into people stretching the meaning of a sentence and making an arbitrarily extendable example. Here, one could probably do this with a list like "a man, a plan, a canal, ..." with ends that work as an instruction either way. It might be tempting to try to rule away such things, but it's an arms race you really can't fight. I think such questions unfortunately just don't work here.

Comment: Here's an extendable example: "Watch the road, the bridge, the median, the forest, the sky, the ..., the signs, the monitor."

Comment: @xnor "monitor the (big list)" in short? I take your point. In some ways I'd like to rule that out, but some of my favourite questions here have been open to such answers, some of which were still quite creative.

Comment: @H.Modh "drive and drink mix don't"?  For that matter, "Don't mix drink and drive" should surely be "...driv*ing*".

Comment: `Please Drive Slowly` => `Slowly Drive Please` and `Please Turn on Green` => `Green ON Turn Please`

Comment: @H.Modh that looks like an answer to me.  I have a 3 as well (which is actually real and inspired the Q), but I won't post it yet.

Comment: Okay, then I'll post it in an answer box... :P

Comment: @ChrisH does the instruction have to have the same meaning in both systems?

Comment: Common sign that makes just as much sense (i.e. very little) forward or backward: those diamond-shaped signs that read "GO CHILDREN SLOW".  Those have always bothered me.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman slightly different but reminds me of the local "slow farmer ahead" warning

Comment: @MD-Tech,on the contrary I considered how to implement a bonus for contrasting meanings. In the end I deliberately left it open.

Comment: I would like to see an example where the text gives *different* instructions to UK vs US drivers.

Comment: @EngineerToast so would I. The example given by AndyT could of course give an asymmetric sequence, but we should be able to do better than that (and not by exploiting different definitions). I have an idea but would rather not post it myself (head start and it's not great) .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 8):

As I mentioned in the comments, this was inspired by a real painted sign (in the UK) which was slowly revealed to me as I approached it in the dark:

> LEFT
>
> TURN
>
> ONLY

And means exactly the same in the US convention.

[Here it is on street view](https://goo.gl/maps/3VCRkGKYytu).

(Self-answer to use spoiler mask)

Answer (score 2):

Ans:

> 1. Please Drive Slowly => Slowly Drive Please
> 2. Please Turn on Green => Green ON Turn Please

3-word and 4-word answers.

Comment: your second implies that the light will turn green when you turn though

Answer (score 2):

As @xnor says, there's always a way of breaking "the longest". Here is one such way (breaking method in bold:

> Please
>
> Turn
>
> Left
>
> **Then**
>
> Indicate
>
> Right
>
> **Then**
>
> Turn
>
> Right
>
> **Then**
>
> Indicate
>
> Left

becomes:

> Left
>
> Indicate
>
> **Then**
>
> Right
>
> Turn
>
> **Then**
>
> Right
>
> Indicate
>
> **Then**
>
> Left
>
> Turn
>
> Please

This format can be extended/repeated ad nauseum.

Comment: I didn't stipulate one word per line, but maybe I should have done. The letter sizing in real examples is such that an instruction of 9 characters including a space will break. Single long words tend to be abbreviated or compressed at least around here, so a rule of "max 9 chars/line" wouldn't work. I've seen examples in Welsh with 2 words on a line (I assume the same can exist in English in the UK but have no evidence) so "1 word /line" is also out. In other words I acknowledge a weakness in my challenge.

Comment: I feel like this is some serious loophole-exploitation (but not in the way you think) - It seems unreasonable to accept entire sentences per line (@ChrisH has added a comment as I was posting this, to this effect)

Comment: @ChrisH - I took inspiration from your xkcd reference which had "I read" on one line. Please feel free to edit the question, it's probably not too late if you're only invalidating my answer. And I don't mind because I think this would be a great question if all loopholes could be closed. That's a big if, but hey, we can try :)

Comment: A specific rule might be tricky. I'll have a go.

Comment: @ChrisH - Don't bother, I think I broke my "fix" already, see edit.

Comment: @question_asker - One word per line version has a similar problem, see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't say one-per-line necessarily, just that > 2 words-ish was excessive. I'm not sure what you mean about one-per-line having a similar problem, though

Comment: @question_asker - Because you can have a single word instruction. And my method of breaking it is to have one instruction per line. I realised I did slightly change my method of breaking though, hence why I've changed where the bold focus of my answer (highlighting the method).

Comment: Also - advising people to "Left Indicate" and then "Right Turn" is probably a bad idea unless they're fleeing from pursuers...

Answer (score 2):

Noting that the question doesn't specify that the instruction must necessarily be *the same* when read in each direction, I submit for consideration:

> DUCK
>  CROSSING
>  AHEAD AT
>  LOW
>  BRIDGE
>  CAUTION

Read UK-style, this becomes:

> Duck crossing ahead at low bridge: caution

US-style, it becomes:

> Caution: bridge low ahead at crossing; duck!

Answer (score 1):

From the campus where I work:

> HUMP
>  SPEED
>  SLOW

which I could parse as:

> HUMP SPEED: SLOW!

or

> SLOW! SPEED HUMP.

Granted, the first interpretation isn't really driving related, so it probably isn't actually a contender. But somewhat amusing nonetheless!

Comment: The first *could* be defining an appropriate speed for crossing the speed humps. It's a good one.